# Why can't the general term formula and summation formula of this sequence be solved?

Tags: differential-equations

```
Clear["Global`*"]
RSolve[{s[n] == 1 - n a[n], a[n] == s[n] - s[n - 1], 
  a[1] == s[1] == 1/2}, {s[n], a[n]}, n]
```

Why can't we find out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably obvious, but the equations can be solved independently. First, eliminate `a[n]`:

```
Solve[{s[n]==1-n a[n],a[n]==s[n]-s[n-1]},{a[n],s[n]}]
(*{{a[n] -> -((-1 + s[-1 + n])/(1 + n)),s[n] -> -((-1 - n s[-1 + n])/(1 + n))}} *)
```

Using the second solution solve for `s[n]`:

```
RSolve[{s[n]==-((-1-n s[-1 + n])/(1 + n)),s[1] == 1/2},{s[n]}, n]
(* {{s[n] -> n/(1 + n)}} *)
```

and using the latter find `a[n]`:

```
a[n] -> -((-1 + s[-1 + n])/(1 + n)) /.s[n_] -> n/(1 + n) // FullSimplify
(* a[n] -> 1/(n + n^2) *)
```

which also satisfies the constraint/initial condition that `a[1]==1/2`.